# Is it possible to publishing .Net Core Worker Service for Linux and Windows without modifiying Program.cs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, daemon

I followed documentations and articles about Worker Service projects, and created a service that i want to host for Windows as a Windows service and for Linux as a daemon.

For hosting as a Windows Service, i need to add .UseWindowsService() (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsService).
For hosting as a daemon, i need to add .UseSystemd() (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd).

What i wonder, can i use something like #if directive, and publish for windows and linux without modifiying the Program.cs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the OS version at runtime, e.g. on Windows or Linux, without using a conditional compilation statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-on-windows-or-linux-without-using)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153797/c-sharp-preprocessor-differentiate-between-operating-systems) one.

Comment: @GuruStron i'll implemented the second one, will give it a try.

Comment: @GuruStron i resolved it with second comment. Thank you.

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) .UseWindowsService() .UseSystemd() .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); }); }    .UseWindowsService() and .UseSystemd() are NOOP so they will only work in their respective environments, So Windows one will see its not windows and just do nothing.

Comment: @coolcake thank you for your answer. I replaced my previous code with yours.